# State Pattern: one state for multiple objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

***What I have:***

Entity `A` which can be in few states (about 10). There are a lot of `A` entities.

**I want to change all entites with state `Y` or `Z` or any other state.**

***Variant 1***

I can use singleton state object with collection of entities with this state:

```
@Service(value="SomeState")
@Scope("singleton")
class SomeState {
  List<A> entities = new LinkedList<A>();
  //...
}
```

*advantage:* quick search by state

*disadvantege:* there will be thousands of entities. It isn't a good idea to hold all of those entities in memory.

***Variant 2:***

I can leave `SomeStatus` stateless and perform a search through the whole database. Something like `getAllEntitiesByStatus(Status status)`.

*advantage:* has no need to hold entities in memory

*disadvantage:* slow search through the whole database

***Questions:***

1. *Is it possible to achieve quick search with no OutOfMemoryException risk?*
2. *May be better ideas?*

Comment: What **evidence** do you have for this assertion: "disadvantage: slow search through the whole database"?

Comment: Go through thousands of entities and check for each if status equals to `Z`. Seems slow. Doesn't it?

Comment: no if you have an index on `status` column

Comment: In such case, how can I index a string column?

Comment: If you are using a normal SQL database: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

Comment: That being said: "Thousands" of items in memory should not be a problem unless they are huge. Alternatively you could use some kind of smart reference, that would just keep a database ID reference to the actual item. This would be a bit more OO than doing a database lookup on a string value...